# VLCJ doesn't play video when using getClass().getResource()

Tags: java, video, vlcj

I'm making a game, but it depends on videos; I hadn't worked before with videos so I used VLCJ as it was the first thing that popped up in YouTube. Anyway, the thing is that when I use `getClass().getResource()` and I execute the jar, it doesn't load the media. So what I need, is that the media can be opened from a jar.

```
String path1 = getClass().getResource("/media/introVideo.mp4").getFile(); //Not works (I want this to work)

String path2 = getClass().getResource("/media/introVideo.mp4").toExternalForm());  //Not works (I want this to work)

String path3 = getClass().getResource("/media/introVideo.mp4").toString());  //Not works (I want this to work)

String path4 = getClass().getResource("/media/introVideo.mp4").getFile().replace("/", "\\"); //Works (Not what I need)

String path5 = new File("src\\media\\introVideo.mp4").toString(); //Works (Not what I need)
```

The error that I get when I use path1, path2 & path3 are the following:

```
libdvdnav: Using dvdnav version 6.0.0
libdvdread: Could not open D:\Programming\HyperDance\\D:\Programming\HyperDance\build\classes\media\introVideo.mp4 with libdvdcss.
libdvdread: Can't open D:\Programming\HyperDance\\D:\Programming\HyperDance\build\classes\media\introVideo.mp4 for reading
libdvdnav: vm: failed to open/read the DVD
[000000001c5ed6a0] filesystem stream error: cannot open file D:\Programming\HyperDance\\D:\Programming\HyperDance\build\classes\media\introVideo.mp4 (Invalid argument)
[000000001c5e3d00] main input error: Your input can't be opened
[000000001c5e3d00] main input error: VLC is unable to open the MRL 'file:///D:/Programming/HyperDance/%2FD%3A%2FProgramming%2FHyperDance%2Fbuild%2Fclasses%2Fmedia%2FintroVideo.mp4'. Check the log for detail
```

**Snippet:**

```
import com.sun.jna.Native;
import com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary;
import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.Color;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import uk.co.caprica.vlcj.binding.LibVlc;
import uk.co.caprica.vlcj.player.MediaPlayerFactory;
import uk.co.caprica.vlcj.player.embedded.EmbeddedMediaPlayer;
import uk.co.caprica.vlcj.player.embedded.windows.Win32FullScreenStrategy;
import uk.co.caprica.vlcj.runtime.RuntimeUtil;

public class Test extends JFrame {

  static Test frame;
  static Canvas canvas;

    public Test() {
        canvas = new Canvas();
          canvas.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        add(canvas);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        frame = new Test();
          frame.setSize(1047,615);
          frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
          frame.setVisible(true);
          frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        NativeLibrary.addSearchPath(RuntimeUtil.getLibVlcLibraryName(),"C:\\Program Files\\VideoLAN\\VLC");
          Native.loadLibrary(RuntimeUtil.getLibVlcLibraryName(), LibVlc.class);
          MediaPlayerFactory mpf = new MediaPlayerFactory();
          EmbeddedMediaPlayer emp = mpf.newEmbeddedMediaPlayer(new Win32FullScreenStrategy(frame));
            emp.setVideoSurface(mpf.newVideoSurface(canvas));
          //↓ How do I fix the importing of the media ↓
            emp.prepareMedia(new Object().getClass().getResource("/media/introVideo.mp4").getFile());
          //↑ The parameter only accepts Strings ↑
            emp.play();
    }
}
```

**Summing up:**

- I need to play a video from a jar.
- The video is played when I don't use `getClass().getResource()`, but I need to use it to access the media from the jar.
- The question: How do I play a video using VLCJ from a jar?

Comment: You cannot use `getResource().getFile()` to work. You have to work with `getResource()` or `getResourceAsStream()` without using `getFile()`. Please [edit] your question to include the source code you have as a [mcve].

Comment: First, vlcj needs the path to be a string so it is necessary to use getFile() and I dont think a a minimal reproducible example is needed because nothing depends on the structure of my code.

Comment: Try passing the string representation of the `URL` (i.e. `URL#toString()`/`URL#toExternalForm()`). And a [mre] would still be helpful, because then we know what methods you're trying to call which we can then read the documentation of. The documentation would (well, should) tell us if the argument should be a URL or a simple file path; or maybe there's a different method you could invoke.

Comment: Have you tried using `getClass().getResource(...).toString()`? If that doesn't work, it's possible the library does not support playing media that's embedded in a JAR file. Could you extract the media somewhere and then play the media from the new external file?

Comment: yes I've tried it and it didn't work (path3). Could you in an official answer teach me how to extract the media somewhere and play it, please?

Comment: A resource is an entry in a .jar file.  It is not a file and it will never be a file.  You cannot coerce it to a file using `getFile()` (which does not return a valid file name) or by any other means.  You need to copy the resource to another directory, like the system’s temporary directory.

Comment: Yes, Java can access media inside a jar, I've tried it with images and it works. Away from that I like your suggestion of creating a temp file.

Comment: Yes, JavaFX can access media inside a JAR file but that doesn't mean VLCJ can. As I understand it, VLCJ delegates to LibVLC which is not written in Java. It's possible, maybe probable, that LibVLC has no idea how to read resources embedded in a JAR file (which is really just a ZIP file). That being said, you look to be trying to play an MP4 file. For that, you might be able to use [JavaFX's media API](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/13/javafx.media/javafx/scene/media/package-summary.html), though that API is considerably less feature-rich compared to VLC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I already found the solution:

- First, I put the jar inside the folder `Surprise` along another folder that contains the video.
- Then, I make the program search for a text file `guide.txt` that is inside the jar to know the location of my `Surprise` folder.
- Finally, I replaced the `guide.txt` path with the path of the video:

  C:/Users/Steve/Desktop/Surprise/ **HyperDance-BTS.jar!** /media/guide.txt

  -> C:/Users/Steve/Desktop/Surprise/ **videos** /introVideo.mp4

**Folders:**

- Surprise (C:, D:, whatever disc:)

  - HyperDance-AC/DC.jar

    - Guide.txt
    - Media (images and sounds)
  - Videos(Hidden folder)

    - introVideo.mp4

**Snippet:**

```
import com.sun.jna.Native;
import com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary;
import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.Color;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import uk.co.caprica.vlcj.binding.LibVlc;
import uk.co.caprica.vlcj.player.MediaPlayerFactory;
import uk.co.caprica.vlcj.player.embedded.EmbeddedMediaPlayer;
import uk.co.caprica.vlcj.player.embedded.windows.Win32FullScreenStrategy;
import uk.co.caprica.vlcj.runtime.RuntimeUtil;

public class Test extends JFrame {

  static Test frame;
  static Canvas canvas;
  static int video = 1;

    public Test() {
        canvas = new Canvas();
          canvas.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        add(canvas);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        frame = new Test();
          frame.setSize(1047,615);
          frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
          frame.setResizable(false);
          frame.setVisible(true);
          frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        NativeLibrary.addSearchPath(RuntimeUtil.getLibVlcLibraryName(),"C:\\Program Files\\VideoLAN\\VLC");
          Native.loadLibrary(RuntimeUtil.getLibVlcLibraryName(), LibVlc.class);
          MediaPlayerFactory mpf = new MediaPlayerFactory();
          EmbeddedMediaPlayer emp = mpf.newEmbeddedMediaPlayer(new Win32FullScreenStrategy(frame));
            emp.setVideoSurface(mpf.newVideoSurface(canvas));

            if (video==1) {
                emp.prepareMedia(url("introVideo.mp4"));
                emp.play();
            }
            if (video==2) {
                //Another video
            }
    }

    static String url (String video) {
        String mrl = new Object().getClass().getResource("/media/guide.txt").getFile();
        String url = mrl.replace("/", "\\").split("\\\\",2)[1].split("Surprise")[0].concat("Surprise\\videos\\"+video);
          return url;
    }
}
```

Is there a better way or a more official one to do this?

Comment: Not a complete answer so commenting... I would just extract the media from your jar file at run-time (e.g. to the system temporary folder, or the application current directory), maybe checking if it were already extracted there or not. You can get an InputStream for your in-jar media via class.getResourceAsStream() and then copy it to some OutputStream that you control the location of and play it from there.